# "The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests." (self hosted agents)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-deployment

Running pipeline for ci/cd DSC causes queued items title error message.  Worked a month ago without queueing.  Rebooted AzureDevops server.   Deleted client in deployment pool that was not responding.  No parallel jobs info since this is hosted on our server - option is not available.

The agent pool is online and I've updated the client version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests. (self hosted agents)

When you add tasks to the Pipeline, it could automatically add agent demands.

For example:

[image]

In this case,  when running the pipeline, it will stuck in queue if there is no agent can meet the demands.

[image]

You can check the Agent demands in the Pipeline and the **Agent Capabilities** in **Agent Pool -> Target Agent -> Capabilities**. The configuration required in agent demands needs to match the configuration in agent capabilities.

If you are using the YAML Pipeline, there is no field to check the default Agent demands.

You can manually create a Classic Pipeline and add the same tasks to the Classic Pipeline. Then you can check the default agent demands.

Comment: The tasks only use powershell or copyfile.  I don't see a way to view target agent or capabilities.  It's like we're running a different version than what you're seeing.  :/

Comment: @BaconBurner Can you please share the screenshot of the version you see and the screenshot of the  Pipeline definition?

Comment: Version Azure DevOps Server 2022 RC1 (AzureDevOpsServer_20220728.1)

Looking  for pipeline definition

Comment: Pipeline definition has a bunch of stuff I can't post here :/

Comment: @BaconBurner Can you share the current agent version with us?

Comment: Agent.Version 2.181.2 (most of them) target with changes is 2.204.0

Comment: @BaconBurner The agent version 2.204.0 is not the latest version in Azure DevOps Server 2022. Can you upgrade the agent to the latest version and check if it can work? In my side the latest version in Azure DevOps Server 2022 is 2.217.2.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT We are running Azure DevOps Server 2020 with Agent version 2.170.1, which worked fine on Windows 10 Visual Studio 2022 Development Clients.  When installing 2.170.1 on a Windows 11 Client we had this issue.  Updating the agent version to 3.225.0 fixed it.  Thanks!!

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT upgraded and still getting. "The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests. Current position in queue: 1
No agents in pool Dev are currently able to service this request."

Is patch1 relevant to this?  I have not run 1patch1 yet.   Running client v3.225.2 on 19.225.34309.2 (AzureDevOps2022.1).

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: It may be I don't understand the difference between an agent group and a deployment pool.

Comment: We thought the deployment pool was the only requirement but we had an agent in the agent pool that got deleted.  once adding the agent back to the agent pool DSC started running again.